# Can I remove receipts from imported products from my passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, japan, paperwork

I have recently imported books into Canada from Japan.

As I bought in excess of 5000¥, the purchase was tax free and the receipt was stapled to my passport and stamped.

Since I've now come back to Canada and no issues occurred with my imports, **Is it safe to remove the receipts from my passport?**

As it was stamped and stapled, there will remain a trace that something was there. Could this cause problems when I return to Japan at a later time?

Comment: Nice question.  I am fairly sure that most will agree that the answer is yes, of course you can take the recepts out, but finding a reference to support that conclusion may be more difficult.

Comment: Who did this stamping and stapling? The vendor in Japan? Japanese customs? Canadian customs? Immigration? Someone else?

Comment: @Henning It was the vendor in Japan. The customs officer then verified it all when I passed at the customs.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20154/is-it-illegal-to-peel-off-a-visa-from-your-australian-passport

Comment: Incidentally, @hippietrail complained about stapled pieces of paper in Japan in that post :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is **safe** to remove the receipts because **you are supposed to return those receipts** to the Japan Customs counters right after the passport control.

> Submit the Proof of Tax-Free Purchase attached to your passport when leaving the country - 
>   *[(Offical) Japan. Tax-free Shopping Guide](http://tax-freeshop.jnto.go.jp/eng/shopping-guide.php)*

This leads to another question: "[what if I forget to return the receipts?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/28943/6418)".

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, it's safe to remove**.  Japan and quite a few other countries staple their departure cards to the passport, so immigration authorities are used to seeing staple holes on passport pages.